# Configuration Management module fails exporting

Tags: 7, configuration

On a large multisite i have configuration management installed. But it fails to export large lists of e.g. tracked variables. When i click on the "select all" checkbox and proceed to "export to tar file" the site loads and then gets back to the unselected list offering no download file.

It works when the list is small (e.g. content types).

Nothing in the drupal logs.

Does anyone know why or how to debug this? Is it about memory? I have 1024M enabled on the site.

Comment: Does it work in Drush?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have drush on the server... but I'll try locally.

Comment: After setting up this beast locally I could manage to sync the configuration with drush. It took about 10 minutes and the fans were very busy. 

Now, do you have any idea how i can pull off this on the server?

Comment: Has the config been exported before on the server?  The first thing I would try is sending the exported config via drush back up the server via git, etc.